# CreateProcess fails under windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess

I'm trying to compile legacy code from Windows XP under a new environment in Windows 7. It compiles but fails at runtime.

CreateProcess() returns 0 and GetLastError() returns 2, which stands for ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Here is my call to CreateProcess

```
STARTUPINFO StartInfo;
memset(&StartInfo, 0, sizeof(StartInfo));

wcsncpy(astrCommandLine, L"TFTP", MAX_OSCOMMANDLINE_SZ-1); 
BOOL bFuncRetn = CreateProcess(NULL, 
              astrCommandLine,     // command line 
              NULL,          // process security attributes 
              NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
              NULL,          // handles are inherited 
              0,             // creation flags 
              NULL,          // use parent's environment 
              NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
              &StartInfo,          // STARTUPINFO pointer 
              &m_ProcInfo );   // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION
```

Now for the oddities : When instead of tftp I run calc, calc pops up. I can execute whatever is on my command line from anywhere in a command prompt so it tells me that the %PATH% to c:\windows\system32 is known and works correctly.

I tried to force CreateProcessA with ansi strings but I got the same result. I also tried in debug and release configuration and from command line.

Any idea?

EDIT :
both calc.exe and tftp.exe are located in c:\windows\system32 which is in the system path.
running "c:\windows\system32\tftp" does not work

Comment: Is tftp being found by an App Path rather than the system path? That might explain why calc is found but tftp isn't. CreateProcess doesn't use the App Paths. I'm assuming that you are setting StartInfo.cb somewhere.

Comment: There is preciously little hope that this will work.  Surely tftp.exe is not located in your program's default working directory.  Calc.exe is not a problem, it is on the PATH.  Pass the *full* pathname of the .exe, like c:\foo\bar\tfpt.exe.

Comment: I never heard of StartInfo.cb

Comment: Clearly a silly question but are you actually sure there is even tftp.exe on your system you are testing? Windows 7 no longer has tftp client installed by default, you need to add it through the "Windows Features" in "Programs and Features" control panel.

Comment: Have you tried monitoring your program using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)?  That should show exactly which files and registry keys are being read and exactly what's failing.

Comment: @tyranid : Yes I can execute properly from command prompt

Comment: You could use filemon to see what files it's trying to open

Comment: Try experimenting with the command "more".  more.exe should open a command prompt window just like tftp.exe should do.  Each line that you type should be echoed until you type Ctrl+Z.  This will at least show if your current execution environment can open a command prompt window.

Comment: Use `where` command from Command Prompt to know where exactly the TFTP program is (Try: `where tftp`).

Comment: Are you by any chance a 32-bit application running on a 64-bit system? My guess is that the 32-bit version of TFTP.EXE is not installed.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you have a 32 bit application trying to execute a 64 bit Windows command. You do not have to recompile your application as 64 bit to solve the problem. All you have to do is change all occurrences of c:\windows\system32 to c:\windows\SysNative.

In Windows 7 x64, references to c:\windows\system32 from 32 bit programs are automatically redirected to c:\windows\syswow64. Using the special alias c:\windows\SysNative causes Windows 7 to not do the redirect.