# C++ CreateProcess error-code 2 ("ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND") on Windows 7 (64)

Tags: c++, windows, runtime-error, createprocess

I'm trying to create a simple program to test CreateProcess() function in C/C++ on Windows 7 (64). When i pass the CommandLine ("szCmdline") parameter directly it works fine, but if i try to send parameters by getting it from argv and pass to a funcion i'm getting the "Error code 2 ("ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND")" at runtime.

I was looking for a solution and found that "[CreateProcess-fails-under-windows-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003981/createprocess-fails-under-windows-7)" on this forum, but it seems not work for me or i'm doing something wrong.

This is the NewProcess() code:

```
void NewProcess(TCHAR **cmd){

    printf("Argv Inside funcion: %s\n",cmd[1]);
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        cmd[1],         // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    printf("Process ID: %d Started",pi.dwProcessId);
    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    printf("\nProcess ID: %d Terminated!",pi.dwProcessId);

    // Close process and thread handles.
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

And the Main funcion code:

```
void main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    printf("Argv outside function: %s\n",argv[1]);
    //LPTSTR szCmdline = _tcsdup(TEXT("C:\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe"));  <-- **It works fine**

    NewProcess(argv);  // <-- **It doesn't works**
}
```

At runtime, cmd and argv contains the same data but it fails at CreateProcess() call.

Result:

```
E:\C++\VISUAL_STUDIO\NewTest> newtest.exe "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe"
Argv outside function: C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
Argv Inside funcion: C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
CreateProcess failed (2).
```

I tested with "C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe", %windir%\system32\calc.exe , "C:\Windows\SysNative\calc.exe"

Any idea?

Thanks advice

Comment: how are you calling this? Can you post the debug command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that `void main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])` is correct ? In windows, I currently use :

- `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` 8 bits ANSI chars
- `int wmain(int argc, wchar *argv[])` 16 bits UNICODE chars
- `int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])` macro defined

If what you posted if what your use, you could pass a `LPSTR *` to your function which expects a `LPWSTR *` if UNICODE is defined.

Comment: OP is abusing `TCHAR` indeed.

Comment: +1.  I've just confirmed that changing the OPs code to use `wmain` fixes the problem.

Comment: If you use `TCHAR` for `argv`, the correct *main* is `_tmain`